# Failed to load module - intern/node_modules/dojo

Tags: intern

I had to blow away my node_modules directory and when i did npm install it succededed. After that when i run tests like this:

> ./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=test2/intern.local.unit

I get this...

```
node_modules/dojo/loader.js:490
                    throw new Error('Failed to load module ' + module.mid + ' from ' + url + (parent ? ' (parent: ' + parent.mid + ')' : ''));
                    ^

Error: Failed to load module intern/node_modules/dojo/has from /Users/tmcconechy/Dev/controls/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/has.js (parent: intern/node_modules/dojo/has!2!*)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/Users/tmcconechy/Dev/controls/node_modules/dojo/loader.js:490:27)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:324:13)
```

Does anyone have any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: Does the file it is trying to load actually exist? Is your Dev directory part of a Samba share or something like that?

Comment: Yes test2/intern.local.unit exists... (thing is this worked until i messed up my node_packages and reinstalled it all. So thinking maybe its a temp bug in the version i have? "intern": "^3.0.6"?

Comment: Ah! Fixed think i figured this out. I guess its related to node version 5.0.
If i set node back to 0.12.7 and then delete node_modules and npm install it works....

If i set node to 5.0.0 and then delete node_modules and npm install it gives this message..

if i set node to 5.0.1 i get an error on intern@3.0.6 install: `node support/fixdeps.js`

i wonder what the supported version is?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this kind of error testing the intern example (https://github.com/theintern/intern-examples) with dojo. I used node 6.3.1 and executing the command **intern-runner** it generates **Error: Failed to load module intern/node_modules/dojo/has** error. Downgrading node version to a LTS (4.4.7) it works like a charm.